# sed help: replacing conditionally based on next line (prettifying ascii tree output)

Tags: string, awk, sed

I've got a program that gives output like the following:

```
1405565344
  |
  +- 1405722995
  |   |
  |   +- 1405722998
  |   |   |
  |   |   +- 1405724849
  |   |     
  |   +- 1406051621
  |     
  +- 1406051709
  +- 1406733328


[END OF OUTPUT -- OUTPUT DOES NOT INCLUDE THIS LINE]
```

*Note that the very last line is not part of the output; the last two (mostly blank) lines are hidden if I don't add something after them. Also note that the blank line immediately after the last entry has multiple spaces on it, but SO doesn't display them).*

So I want to make this more compact and well.. pretty. Using the following `sed` command...

```
sed -e 's,|,│,g'     \
    -e "s,+,└,"      \
    -e "s,- ,─,"     \
    -e '/^[ │]*$/d'
```

I can convert the above input into:

```
1405565344
  └─1405722995
  │   └─1405722998
  │   │   └─1405724849
  │   └─1406051621
  └─1406051709
  └─1406733328
```

Much better. Ideally though, I'd like it to be this:

```
1405565344
  ├─1405722995
  │   ├─1405722998
  │   │   └─1405724849
  │   └─1406051621
  ├─1406051709
  └─1406733328
```

Small difference, I know, but it makes more sense and is more in line with other output of my program.

So basically: I'd like a way to make `sed` conditionally replace `+` with either `└` or `├`, depending on what's on the line after it. Seems pretty much practically impossible, without taking a completely different track.

Any ideas?

Comment: IMHO, you are beyond the edge of what should be done in sed. Sed it really powerful, and has the notion of  *hold string* that could help. But it will give an unmaintenable ugly mess : if it is too complex, use python (resp perl, ruby, ...)

Comment: @SergeBallesta: that was my feeling as well; however, I thought I'd ask anyway. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -n -e '/| *$/ d;1h;1!H
$ {x
:a
   s/\(\n[ |]*\)+\([^[:cntrl:]]*\1[|+]\)/\1├\2/;t a
:b
   s/\(\n[ |]*\)+/\1└/;t b
   s/|/│/g;s/- /─/g;p
   }' YourFile
```

should do your work. Tested with other char than graphical one (don't pass on my aix).
Test is made to chage to `T` if pattern from begin of line on one line until `+` is the same as next beginning (the one after the first new line). I use [:cntrl:] to catch the non-newline so if there is special char considered as control char, it failed (don't think there is in your file).
If not the case (line with +) change de plus in corner [Modified for optimisation of sed pattern grouping][modfied for corner char and the case of 2 consecutive line with same pattern ended by +]

Comment: `sed` is so ridiculous ... but wow that's awesome @NeronLeVelu. As far as the output, it's perfect with one simple tweak -- changing `/\1L/` to `/\1└/`.

Comment: I spoke too soon. Your amazing code doesn't handle some simpler cases like what I just added to the main post.

Comment: You are right, I forget the case, just a sample tuning :-) (change the `\1|` in line after :a by `\1[|+]` (modified in reply)

Answer (score 1):

Awk way
Could probably be seriously improved but it works as intended.
My machine can't show `├` or `└` so just replace the `#` and `L` with them.
If anyone has any improvements just let me know and i'll update !

```
awk '/\+/{a=$0;b=index($0,"+");next}
a{if(substr($0,b,1)=="|"){$0=gensub(/+/,"#","g",a)}else{$0=gensub(/+/,"L","g",a)}}
/[1-9]/{print $0}' file
```

## Output

```
1405565344
#- 1405722995
|   #- 1405722998
|   |   L- 1405724849
|   L- 1406051621
L- 1406051709
```

Comment: Very nice! My initial inclination was to do it with `awk` but it was late and I didn't even try. I'm learning from your code. You did the hard part; now I just need to make it replace `- ` with `─` and `|` with `│`.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it. gawk's match() function sets a variable RSTART. I check the following line to see what character is at that position.

```
gawk '
    function g(line) {
        gsub(/#/,   "├", line)
        gsub(/-/,   "─", line)
        gsub(/[+]/, "└", line)
        gsub(/[|]/, "│", line)
        return line
    }
    /^[[:blank:]|]*$/ {next} 
    prev {
        while (match(prev, /[+]/)) {
            c=substr($0, RSTART, 1); 
            if (c == "+" || c == "|")
                sub(/[+]/, "#", prev)
            else 
                break
        }
        print g(prev)
    }
    {prev=$0} 
    END {print g($0)}
' file
```

In action:

```
$ echo "1405565344
  |
  +- 1405722995
  |   |
  |   +- 1405722998
  |   |   |
  |   |   +- 1405724849
  |   |     
  |   +- 1406051621
  |   +- foobar
  |     
  +- 1406051709
  +- barfoo" |
awk '
    function g(line) {
        gsub(/[+]/, "└", line)
        gsub(/#/, "├", line)
        gsub(/-/,"─", line)
        gsub(/[|]/, "│", line)
        return line
    }
    /^[[:blank:]|]*$/ {next} 
    prev {
        while (match(prev, /[+]/)) {
            c=substr($0, RSTART, 1); 
            if (c == "+" || c == "|")
                sub(/[+]/, "#", prev)
            else 
                break
        }
        print g(prev)
    }
    {prev=$0} 
    END {print g($0)}
'
```

```
1405565344
  ├─ 1405722995
  │   ├─ 1405722998
  │   │   └─ 1405724849
  │   ├─ 1406051621
  │   └─ foobar
  ├─ 1406051709
  └─ barfoo
```

Comment: Awesome glenn! I love awk. Learning from what you did now. Only 1 nitpick: your assumption about how the original program would generate the word "foobar" (i.e., a child immediately following a child of the same parent) is wrong. I've updated the original input a bit to show you that in that case, it actually doesn't add an extra blank line; instead it puts the plus sign on the very next line. (Stupid in inconsistent if you ask me, but that's what I have to work with.)

Comment: Not a problem. I strip out "blank" lines already. Will not affect my program.

Comment: It's not just about the blank lines. Take a look at the input -- I added an additional line (like you did with `foobar`). It causes your awesome awk script to fumble.

Comment: Hmm, not for me. Updated my example.

Comment: it has to do with the extra spacing. Read the screenshot at http://b19.org/awk_glenn.png from left to right.

Comment: I like this solution much more than the one with `sed`; however I haven't taken the time to figure out how to fix what's wrong with this one ... so ... I'm accepting the other one. Thanks so much glenn for taking the time to answer. I've not used `match()` before, so will definitely be playing with this some more.

Answer (score 0):

My logic is to use awk, | as the tokenizer and using the length of $NF to decide which line to print

```
cat <ip_file.txt> | awk -F'|' '{if(length($NF)>5)print $0;}'
```

and i got the following output for your input

```
1405565344
  +- 1405722995
  |   +- 1405722998
  |   |   +- 1405724849
  |   +- 1406051621
  +- 1406051709
```

NOTE: Replacing the +- is still pending

Comment: That's cool Raghuram -- I use `awk` and I never would've thought to do it like that; however, it doesn't really help address the problem I have (since I can do that much with a simple sed command).